# use cookies to store tokens

Tags: reactjs, express

i'm building an app where i need to authorize users to login i read that localstorage isnt a safe option so i'm opting for cookies to store tokens for now i believed i successed to store tokens in cookies but i dont know what to do next , how to use them in client side here is my code

here is back end : 
routes :

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var Controller = require('./controller')
var authController = require('./authController')
var BooksIdeaController = require('./BooksIdeaController')
router.post('/register',Controller.register);
router.post('/login',authController.login);
router.post('/booksIdea/:id',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.addComment)
router.post('/booksIdea/addbook',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.addBookIdea)
router.get('/booksIdea/show',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.showBookIdea)
router.put('/booksIdea/edit/:id',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.UpdateBookIdea)
router.delete('/booksIdea/delete/:id',authController.verify,BooksIdeaController.DeleteBookIdea)
module.exports = router;
```

authController.js file

```
 const con = require('./db');
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const express = require('express')
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    const app = express()
    module.exports.login=function(req,res){
        var username=req.body.name;
        var password=req.body.password;
        con.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',[username], function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) {
              res.json({
                status:false,
                message:'there are some error with query'
                })
          }else{
            if(results.length >0){
              bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function (err, result) {
                if (result == true) {
            jwt.sign({user:results},'configSecret',(err,token)=>{
              // res.json({
              //   token:token
              // })
              res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true })
                .sendStatus(200);
              res.send('About this wiki');
            });



                //   res.json({
                //     status:true,
                //     message:'successfully authenticated'
                // })
                } else {
                  res.json({
                          status:false,
                          message:"username and password does not match"
                         });
                }
              });
            }
            else{
              res.json({
                  status:false,    
                message:"username does not exits"
              });
            }
          }
        });
    }

    module.exports.home=function(req,res){
    res.send('hello');
    }
    //////
    // if(password==results[0].password){

      // }else{
      //    
      // }
      module.exports.verify = function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
        // Get auth header value
        const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
        // Check if bearer is undefined
        if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
          // Split at the space
          const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
          // Get token from array
          const bearerToken = bearer[1];
          // Set the token
          req.token = bearerToken;
          // Next middleware
          next();
        } else {
          // Forbidden
          res.sendStatus(403);
        }

      }
```

here is react part

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const login = user => {
  return axios
    .post('http://localhost:5001/login', {
      name: user.name,
      password: user.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: add your auth controller as well

Comment: its there i added it

Comment: your cookie can be accessible by node as req.cookie.So for that, you can create on middleware which check if coockie is related to cookie stored in database then return authenticated else return unauthenticated in response.

Comment: thank you for your answer , can u suggest me a link where this topic is explained

Answer (score 0):

**REACT Side:**

HOC for check your authenticated or not calling  /api/auth request to server

```
/**
 * auth.js : it handles user is authenticated or not
 * 
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function(ComposedClass,reload){
    class AuthenticationCheck extends Component{

        state = {
            loading : true
        }

        componentWillMount () {
            this.props.dispatch(auth())
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
            this.setState({
                loading : false
            })

            if(!nextProps.admin.login.isAuth){
                if(reload){
                    this.props.history.push('/login')
                }
            }
        } 

        render(){
            if(this.state.loading){
                return <div className="loader"> Loading... </div>
            }
            return(
               <ComposedClass {...this.props} users={this.props.users} />
            )
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state){
        console.log(state)
        return{
            admin: state.users
        }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticationCheck)
}
```

Pass your all route to that HOC Component like

```
import React from 'react';
import  { Switch , Route  } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home/home';
import Users from './components/UsersView/users';
import User from  './components/UserView/user';
import FourOFour from  './components/FourOFour/fourofour';
import AddUser from './containers/Admin/add';
import EditUser from './containers/Admin/edit';
import UserContainer from './containers/User/user_container.js';
import Login from './containers/Login/login';
import Signup from './containers/Signup/signup';
import Auth from './hoc/Auth/auth';
import Logout from './components/Logout/logout';


import Layout from './hoc/Layout/layout';


const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Switch> 
                <Route path="/signup" exact  component={ Auth(Signup,false) } />
                <Route path="/logout" exact  component={ Auth(Logout,true) } />
                <Route path="/login" exact  component={ Auth(Login,false) } />
                <Route path="/users/add" exact  component={ Auth(AddUser,false) } /> 
                <Route path="/users/:id/edit" exact  component={ Auth(EditUser,true) } />          
                <Route path="/users/:id" exact component={ Auth(UserContainer,true) } />
                <Route path="/users" exact component={ Auth(Users,false) } />
                <Route path="/" exact  component={ Auth(Home,null) } />
                <Route component={FourOFour}/>     
            </Switch>
        </Layout>

    );
};

export default Routes;
```

**NODE Side:**

```
 /**
 * auth : Middleware which chack your tocken is valide or not
 */
    const  { Admin } = require('../models/admin');

    let auth = (req,res,next) =>{
        let token = req.cookies.auth;

        Admin.findByToken(token,(err,admin)=>{

            if (!admin) return res.json({
                error : true
            })

            req.token = token;
            req.admin = admin;

            next();
        })

    }


    module.exports = { auth }
```

You can use auth in your route where you want to check authentication.

```
//admin auth : 
app.get("/api/auth",auth,(req,res) => { 
    console.log(auth)
    res.json({
        isAuth : true,
        id : req.admin._id,
        email : req.admin.email,
    })
})
```

For more visit my [Mern App Project](https://github.com/Prkarena/mern_app.git)